# Creating a new function with various arguments in R

Tags: r

I'm supposed to create a function that shortens a written text. I have all the necessary arguments. But, I am unsure of how to actually create the function. I really need the help. Here are the arguments:

```r
### Replacing multiple consecutive spaces by a single space
gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", text,perl = TRUE) # text is the written text of various words with multiple spaces

### Abbreviating words and replacing extra characters with a full stop
gsub("(?<=\\w{5})\\w+", ".", text, perl = TRUE) # text is the written text containing words you want to abbreviate

### Removing specific words 
stopwords <- c("the", "really", "truly", "very")

x <- unlist(strsplit(text, " "))
x <- x[!x %in% stopwords]
paste(x, collapse = " ")

### Extracting first sentence of each paragraph
unlist(lapply(text, function(x) str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1]))
```

Comment: If these functions work and should be applied sequentially to the same dataset, why not just use pipes (`%>%` or `|>`)? As in `text %>% gsub.... %>% gsub....`

Comment: I suggest you wrap every step of your transformation into a function call, then use pipes

Comment: it also might be worth checking out mgsub as you can eliminate the use of multiple gsubs through vectors of replacement and patterns

Comment: @GuedesBF, thanks for the reply. I'm really bad at this. How do I wrap every step into a function? Do I do this?

replace_spaces <- function(text) {
  
  gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", text,perl = TRUE)
  return(text)
  
}

Comment: @cgvoller, is there a reason to use the `mgsub` package when it can be done directly with a call to `Map` and `Reduce`?

Comment: @lmran, for the first function, it woul be something like `replace_spaces <- function(text) { gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", text, perl = TRUE) }` you do not have to use 'return', as the function will return the output of the last function call (in this case, the call for gsub) by default

Comment: I've done all these functions. Do you mind checking if the format is correct @GuedesBF?

replace_spaces <- function(text) { 
  gsub("^ *|(?<= ) | *$", "", text, perl = TRUE) }

abb_words <-  function(text) {
  gsub("(?<=\\w{5})\\w+", ".", text, perl = TRUE) }

### I'm not sure about this one

rmv_words <- function(text) {   
 stopwords <- c("the", "really", "truly", "very")
x <- unlist(strsplit(text, " "))
x <- x[!x %in% stopwords]
paste(x, collapse = " ") }

Comment: The last function as well: 

### Not sure on this one as well 
first_sentence <- function(text) {
lapply(text, function(x) str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])
unlist(lapply(text, function(x) str_split(x, "\\.", simplify = T)[1])) }